# How do you interpret a changepoint graph?

Tags: r, change-point

What is the correct way of interpreting a changepoint graph? Here is what R gives for changepoint analysis of the mean of a data set:

```
----------
Changepoint type      : Change in mean 
Method of analysis    : AMOC 
Assumed Distribution  : Normal 
Type of penalty       : SIC with value, 4.770685 
Maximum no. of cpts   : 1 
Changepoint Locations : 15 118
```

So changes occurred at t=15 and t = 118?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the [changepoint](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/changepoint/index.html) package (which from the output I presume you are) then the changepoint locations always end with n.  Thus the length of your data is 118 and there is a single change in mean at 15.

For info AMOC means At Most One Change and thus the maximum number of changepoints the method will identify is 1.  As 1 has been identified then you should use an alternative method, see documentation for options.

You mention a changepoint graph but as far as I can see from your question you haven't plotted anything.  To see the results on the original series you can use

```
out<-cpt.mean(data)
plot(out)
```